# Matrix params for Spring RestTemplate

Tags: java, spring, restful-architecture, resttemplate

I can't find anywhere an information is `RestTemplate` support `matrix params` at all? Seams not. But maybe someone knows the answer for sure.

I'm trying to write Rest Client using `Spring RestTemplate`.

Comment: Please enlight me. What are `matrix params`?

Comment: http://www.w3.org/DesignIssues/MatrixURIs.html

Comment: http://www.somesite.com/map/color;lat=50;long=20;scale=32000 Matrix vars are `lat=50`;`long=20`;`scale=32000`

Comment: \you can use spEx in you `@RequestMapping` the parse the path info. Note that these are not valid http parameters.

Comment: I can't modify server-side.